# Где в Google Sheets писать скрипт?

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet

Где в google sheets писать скрипт, который мог работать с ячейками, изменять данные и т.п.?

Answer (score 0):

Откроете редактор и уже можно писать[image: Здесь]